# Upload image worked in local but not work in my hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a project ASP MVC.In my project i have a form for upload image i used

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/"));
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Files[0].ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string url = path + home.Image;
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path + home.Image))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path+home.Image);
                }
                FileInfo FInfo = new FileInfo(Request.Files[0].FileName);
                string filename = "sample";
                string ImagePath = path;
                Request.Files[0].SaveAs(ImagePath + filename + FInfo.Extension);
                }
```

Above this code in my local system perfectly .I hosted my project in my site.But it now working in my site.

Any one know please help me

Thanks

Comment: did you check if the directory images exists and you have proper permissions?

Comment: Yes there is a directory called images and it have the premission for upload image

Comment: check the write permission of the /images folder in your server.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your path for image folder,
Please check that you have write permission on  folder in which you uploading image,
If you do not have permission then go to security tab and  allow full control to everyone,